# izpack-maven-plugin is not including native libraries by default

Tags: maven, izpack

I have specified the standard shortcut-generating natives in my installation XML file:

```
<natives>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll"/>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll"/>
    <native type="izpack" name="WinSetupAPI.dll"/>
    <native type="izpack" name="WinSetupAPI_x64.dll"/>
</natives>
```

However, when I run izpack:izpack and run the resultant jar, it hangs on the shortcutPanel saying it can't locate the library.  When I copy the .dll's into the same directory it works.

Any idea how I can specify that the files be included into the final jar?

Answer (score 4):

for IzPack 4 you must not use a  wrapper element here, just use the following:

```
<native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll"/>
<native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll"/>
<native type="izpack" name="WinSetupAPI.dll"/>
<native type="izpack" name="WinSetupAPI_x64.dll"/>
```

This is also documented in the installation.dtd:

`<!ELEMENT installation (info, packaging?, properties?,
variables?,dynamicvariables?,conditions?,installerrequirements?,
                        guiprefs?, locale, resources?, panels,
                        listeners?, packs, jar*, native*)>`

For IzPack 5 the dtd has been changed to the syntax you are using above.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.izpack/izpack-native -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-native</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```