# Why is the ShortcutPanel not shown in izpack?

Tags: installation, shortcut, izpack

I am trying to make an installer with izpack 4.3.5. While installing, a shortcut should be added to the users Desktop. Though I have added the ShortcutPanel and did not add the skipOnNotSupported no panel is shown and no shortcut is created though it complies successfully.

I already took a look at the following post ([izpack: create shortcut on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295544/izpack-create-shortcut-on-windows)) but couldn't figure out my mistake.

Here is part of my install-file:

```
<panels>
<panel classname="TargetPanel"/>
<panel classname="PacksPanel"/>
<panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>
<panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
<panel classname="SimpleFinishPanel"/>
</panels>

<packs> 
   ...
</packs>

<resources>
    <res src="shortcut.xml" id="shortcut.xml"/>
</resources>
<natives>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll"/>
    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll"/>
</natives>
```

And here is my shortcut XML:

```
<izpack:shortcuts version="5.0"
                  xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/shortcuts"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/shortcuts http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-shortcuts-5.0.xsd">
    <shortcut
        name = "test"
        target = "$INSTALL_PATH\test.jar"
        description="test"
        programGroup="true"
        desktop="yes"
        applications="yes"
        startMenu="yes"/>
    <lateShortcutInstall />
</izpack:shortcuts>
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I also tried to remove the lateShortcutInstall, but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make install files for izPack version 5 work with izPack 4.3.5 (notice the version="5.0" in the shortcut XML?). This will not work as the format has changed in subtle details.

I suggest that you move to a current izPack 5 version (5.1.0 has just been released). It is actively maintained, more stable and better documented than 4.3.5.

If you are stuck on 4.3.5 please read my other post here: [izpack-maven-plugin is not including native libraries by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179915/izpack-maven-plugin-is-not-including-native-libraries-by-default) and remove the `<natives>` element.